# Selective update using Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have one function which updates a MySQL table. I need to do a selective update of fields according to whether the parameters are present or not. This is how I have coded it right now.

```
        String sql =  "";
        if (employerId > 0) sql = sql + "employerid=?,";
        if (status != null) sql += " status=?,";
        if(printurl != null) sql += " url=?";
        if (sql.endsWith(",")) sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length()-1);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update employer set "
                + sql
                + "where id=?");

       if (employerId > 0) ps.setInt(1, employerId);
       if (status != null) ps.setString(2,status);
```

When I do like this, how do I determine the parameter index? According to the parameters present (if conditions), the parameter index will also vary, right? How do I get around with this? Is there a better way to handle this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try a static query as below?

```
String sql =  "update employer set employerid=IF(?=0,employerid,?),"+
              "status=IFNULL(?,status), url=IFNULL(?,url) " +
              "where id=?";
```

Conceptually, I am suggesting to update the column with itself if it is `0` or `null`. This way, you don't need to create dynamic query string or dynamically set the parameters.

Comment: Gives me Syntax error - "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), status=IFNULL("

Comment: Try once without `employerid`. I am bit skeptical because of two '?'. I tried something similar in Oracle using `decode` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The [SqlBuilder](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/) library provides a much better way to do dynamic SQL query generation in java programs.  The [QueryPreparer](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/sqlbuilder/QueryPreparer.html) class specifically addresses the problem you are encountering here by tracking the indexes for you.

disclaimer, i am the primary developer of the SqlBuilder project.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep this for the next project. I am not a Java expert, so it takes time to look into any new library. +1'ed

Answer (score 1):

How about using **arraylist**? When you first checking whether paramaters are existed, add to arraylist. After that, iterating array list and set parameters. In this case,

> it determines not only the parameter index but also avoids for
>   checking parameter existed again.

Like that

```
List paramList = new ArrayList<Object>();

         if (employerId > 0) {
             sql = sql + "employerid=? ,";
             paramList.add(employerId);
         }
         if (status != null) { 
             sql += " status=? ,";
             paramList.add(status);
         }
         if(printurl != null) {
             sql += " url=? ";
             paramList.add(printurl);
         }
         if (sql.endsWith(",")) 
             sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length()-1);

         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update employer set " + sql + "where id=?");

         for(int i=0; i< paramList.size(); i++) {
             if(paramList.get(i) instanceof Integer) {
                 ps.setInt((i + 1), (Integer)paramList.get(i));
             }
             else if(paramList.get(i) instanceof String) {
                 ps.setString((i + 1), (String)paramList.get(i));
             }
         }
         System.out.println(ps);
```

Answer (score 0):

please see the following code:

```
       String sql =  "update employer set ";
        boolean hasParam = false;
        if (employerId > 0){
                sql += " employerid=? ";
                hasParam = true;
        }
        if (status != null){
            if(hasParam){
                sql += " , ";
            }
            sql += " status=? ";
            hasParam = true;
        }
        if(printurl != null){
            if(hasParam){
                sql += " , ";
            }
            sql += " url=?";
        }
        sql += " where id=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

       int index = 1;
       if(employerId > 0){
           ps.setInt(index++, employerId);
       }
       if(status != null){
           ps.setString(index++, status);
       }
       if(printurl != null){
           ps.setString(index++, printurl);
       }
       ps.setInt(index, id);
```